# Google Identity Toolkit - Twitter sign in prompts to authorize app every time

Tags: twitter-oauth, google-identity-toolkit

I've using Twitter as one of the IDPs in my Google Identity Toolkit configuration. I followed all the required steps. I'm able to sign in with Twitter and it works fine for the most part except for 2 issues highlighted below. In my Twitter application settings, Permission is set to "Read only".

1. Every time I try to sign in with Twitter using an account used previously to sign in, it prompts me to "Authorize app" again. As I understand, the authorization should be one time only unless revoked. Why do I need to authorize with every sign in?

I found this thread: https://twittercommunity.com/t/why-does-my-app-need-permission-granted-every-time-the-user-authenticates-through-oauth/10251/5

It seems like `Sign in with Twitter` button seems to be routing to 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize' instead of 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate'. Is this a bug in the GIT?

2. If I click `Cancel` instead of `Authorize app`, it brings me back to my callback page but I get a verifyAssertion error:

`[identitytoolkit] verifyAssertion: {"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"invalid","message":""}],"code":400,"message":""}}`

What is causing this error?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. Identity Toolkit is intended to use https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize because according to https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/reference/get/oauth/authorize, desktop app has to use this. 
   Which platform are you working on?
2. If you click Cancel instead of Authorize, Twitter will redirect user to Identity Toolkit with an error response. As a result, Identity Toolkit cannot verify user's identity, and fails the verifyAssertion.

Comment: Thanks for your response. 1. My application has a Google App Engine (Java) backend. It's not a desktop app. Is there a way I can configure it to use oauth/authenticate? My only purpose is to use it for sign in. 2. It's shows an error "Error code: null." to the user on the UI. I'm not sure that it's a good implementation. Why would we want to show a meaningless error to the user on the UI. Is there a way to suppress the error so that it's not displayed to the user?

Comment: 1. For Twitter, Identity Toolkit currently only supports browser flow where signin/authorize happens on a browser instead of from twitter native app. We will spend some time to understand what Twitter means by "desktop app". 2. There are a different reasons why signin can fail. We will evaluate the possibility of suppressing this error. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: Thanks, Ying. 1. My application is using the browser flow (it's a web application). Hope you can look into it soon. It doesn't make sense to authorize the application for every signin. For now, it seems that the "Twitter" option in the Identity Toolkit is not ready for the browser signin flow. So, I'll take it off and wait for further updates from your team. 2. I appreciate that your team is listening to the feedback and actively responding.

Comment: Quick update - The same "Error code: null" message appears for both Google and Facebook authentication as well when user clicks cancel on the authorize page. Simply returning the user back to the signInCallback page is good enough. The error is meaningless to the user and should be hidden from the view.